# Error in updating item in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have created simple table (username, password), the key is username.
the table contains one item:
{
   "username" : "someuser",
   "password" : "cat"
}

Now, i want to update from "cat" to "dog"

```
dynamodb.updateItem({
    TableName: "users",
    Key: { "username": { "S" : "someuser" } },
    UpdateExpression : "SET password =:pass",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : { ":pass" : { "S" : "dog" } }
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

But i got error:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid attribute value type",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2015-11-14T20:22:36.381Z",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false
}
```

Comment: So what are you attribute types?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found that dynamodb javascript shell is not identical to dynamodb running on AWS.

The error above not occur on real dynamodb.

EDIT:
for example, the following works:

```
       var params = {
            TableName: config.SCRIPTTABLE,
            Key: { id : { S: script.id }},
            UpdateExpression: "SET title = :title, description = :desc, code = :code, tags = :tags, pub = :pub",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":title":   { S: script.title },
                ":desc" :   { S: script.description },
                ":code" :   { S: script.code },
                ":tags" :   { SS: script.tags },
                ":pub"  :   { BOOL: script.pub }
            },
            ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
        };

        dynamodb.updateItem(params, function(err, data)  {

            if (err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                context.fail('INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR');
            } else {
                context.succeed();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the differences were, and how you fixed it? I am coming across a similar situation.

Comment: If i remember correctly, the differences is related to using in quotation marks for json keys. I add sample of working code in my original answer above.